# What does it mean by "level sets of $\bar{G}$, a collection of forms, partition those of $\bar{F}$, another collection of forms"

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was reading an article and I was wondering if someone could explain me what a certain phrase meant.

Let $\bar{F}$ be a collection of integral forms of degree less than or equal to $d$. And suppose $\bar{G}$ is a collection of rational forms of degree less than or equal to $d$ such that it satisfies:

Each form of the $\bar{F}$ can be written as a rational polynomial expression of the forms of $\bar{G}$. In particular, the level sets of $\bar{G}$ partition those of $\bar{F}$

I am confused with the very last sentence above. I would appreciate any clarification! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f_1,\cdots,f_k\in\overline{F}$ are expressible as $f_i(\vec{x})=h_i(g_1,g_2,\cdots,g_l)$ where $g_1,\cdots,g_l\in\overline{G}$ then

$$\left\{\vec{x}~~\left|~~\begin{array}{c} f_1(\vec{x})=\lambda_1  \\ \vdots \\ f_k(\vec{x})=\lambda_k \end{array}\right. \right\}={\large \bigsqcup_{\substack{h_1(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_l)=\lambda_1 \\ \vdots \\ h_k(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_l)=\lambda_k}}} \left\{ \vec{x}~~\left|~~ \begin{array}{c} g_1(\vec{x})=\alpha_1 \\ \vdots \\ g_l(\vec{x})=\alpha_l \end{array}\right.\right\}.$$

Given that every $f(\vec{x})\in\overline{F}$ is expressible as $h(g_1,\cdots,g_l)$ for some $g_1(\vec{x}),\cdots,g_l(\vec{x})\in\overline{G}$, this tells us any level set of $\overline{F}$ is a disjoint union of level sets of $\overline{G}$.

In other words, the level sets of $\overline{G}$ partition the level sets of $\overline{F}$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the clarification!